# Why I could not assign value and display element of list?

Tags: c++, list, arraylist, vector

```
int Square(int lenght)
{
std::vector < int > square(lenght);
for(int counter :square)
    square[counter] = counter * counter ;

for(int counter : square){
    printf("%d",square[counter]);
        cout<<""<<endl;
}
```

**Hi there**

**As you see I have basis code block in cpp . I try to make Range-loop using for loop always taking "0" from terminal awkward.How can I fill out with square values ? What is the problem technically or What would you advice for me at similiar case?**

Comment: You have a vector of lenght elements, all filled with 0.  You take each of those 0, and multiply it by itself resulting in 0, and then set element `square[0]` to 0 as many times as lenght.

Comment: It's also all done to a copy. And it's just the one zero. OP doesn't know how the range-based for loop works at all.

Comment: Correct ! 
Why  dont I put  to inside of vector ?

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < length; ++i) { square[i] = i * i;};`

Comment: @drescherjm Why did I use on vector represention .what is the difference ? If I'II use standard loop usage.I say is it posibble technically ?

Comment: `int i=0; for(auto& elem :square) { elem = i * i; ++i; }` [https://ideone.com/xqoQwY](https://ideone.com/xqoQwY)

Comment: @drescherjm it works.Finally list  full  or empty. where did you put  inputs ?

Comment: You can put length as the size in this code: [https://ideone.com/xqoQwY](https://ideone.com/xqoQwY) instead of 5. Also notice I fixed the range based for loop for the output and got rid of the printf

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int counter :square)
```

Here you are using range based for loop. What this means is that in every step counter will go through elements instead of indices. If you want to use indices you should instead use a standard for loop:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < length; ++counter)
```

Comment: I got it.Already I know standart for loop  usage.What if I need to figure out with range-based loop feature

Comment: @01d what do you want to do exactly? Square every element in array? They are filled with zeroes, so all you will do is get zeroes again. However if your array was filled with some numbers then the correct way to do it with range based loop is like this:
```for(int &element: square) element = element * element;```. Then you print elements like this: ```for(int element: square) std::cout << element << " ";```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the range loop like that. The range loop loops through every element in the vector and assigns the left variable in the loop the value of the element.
E.g. your output code should look like this:

```
for(auto const& val: square){
    std::cout<<val<<std::endl;
}
```